# Should I use ValidateAntiForgeryToken in every POST request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security

I have bunch of page with `HttpPost` request and I got a document from my coworker who scan my site with `Acunetix` (I think). The result says `HTML form without CSRF protection (9)`. The suggestion is to use `Same-origin policy` by implementing Token. My question :

1. From performance vs security standpoint, is it worth it if I use `Token` in every `POST` request? I only use `Token` in sensitive `POST` request like LogIn, Register, Transaction, etc.
2. This is probably not relevant with the title, but why did pentest software like `Acunetix` only list few of my pages as `CSRF` possible risk when I have a lot of pages with `POST` request, how does the detection pattern works?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should include the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute in every HttpPost... assuming you are using best practices and HttpPost means that the request has some kind of side effect.

For a long discussion on the matter, see [This discussion over on IT security SE site.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2120/when-the-use-of-a-antiforgerytoken-is-not-required-needed)

It looks like Acunetix is just reporting this on each page that contains a form with no token present. See [Their documentation](http://acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/web/html-form-without-csrf-protection).